# CPANEL file usage high, greatest number of files in bower_components ckeditor directory

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, ckeditor, filesystem, bower

CiviCRM 4.7.31
WordPress 5.4.1

I am using cPanel on a hosting provider and notice the File Usage is high (file usage is number of files, not space).  I checked to see which directories have the largest number of files.

These subdirectories came up as having the largest number of files. Is there some method to reduce the number of files in this directory? Is it possible there are temporary or cache files within that could be cleared?

total number of files:
4369 ./bower_components
2938 ./bower_components/ckeditor

I want to do a test upgrade with a copy of the site, but I am worried that a full site copy plus the files involved to upgrade may run over the File Usage limit for my hosting provider.